# How to check if Join not exists?

Tags: mysql

I have query in which i add join when condition is true only, also i have other condition when i need to check that join or his alias for existing.

```
c2 IS NOT NULL // doesn't work
```

```js
CASE WHEN c2 IS NOT NULL THEN c2.cost ELSE c.cost END AS cost_opt

LEFT JOIN
costs AS c ON (
  1 = 1
  AND c.id = m.cost_id
)

${entity == 'client' ?
                `
                LEFT JOIN
                  costs AS c2 ON (
                    1 = 1
                    AND c2.provider_id = over.provider_id
                    AND c2.active      IS TRUE
                  )
                `
              : ``
 }
```

Help please

Comment: Show us the tables along with data, and please better describe the logic of your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can't test if a table exists, only a column involved. In your case, since it's a left join:

```
WHERE c2.provider_id IS NOT NULL
```

If you don't want any non-matches you should do a `RIGHT JOIN` which excludes them.

Comment: Unknown column 'c2.provider_id' in 'field list'

Comment: It was in your example, I'm using it here as a demonstration. Use a `RIGHT JOIN` to exclude non-matching rows. You should also remove the pointless `1=1` conditions.